# Facing [{“statusCode”:503,”error”:”Service Unavailable”,”message”:”License is not available.”}] error in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster with the version 8.11.3 with TLS enabled. The cluster was running without any issue for months. But suddenly the cluster stopped working with the error

```
[{“statusCode”:503,”error”:”Service Unavailable”,”message”:”License is not available.”}]
```

I am not able to pinpoint the issue as I have checked the logs of both Kibana and Elasticsearch cluster. I was able to find an issue in [discuss elastic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/statuscode-503-error-service-unavailable-message-license-is-not-available/335741) but there was no proper solution given in the question.

Just an FYI we are using self signed certs for enabling TLS in elastic cluster.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the memory given to the Elasticsearch by ES_JAVA_OPTS.

Try to give more memory by example 1 Gb: ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1g -Xms1g".